# How to fix slow and periodic unresponsiveness with my network?

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7 pro on a Dell Optiplex 380.  I am using an Edimax usb network adapter (EW-7811Un).  The network / internet works just like my other computers when booted to Windows (i.e. the same download speed).  However, when booted to Ubuntu, the network is sometimes slow and sometimes unresponsive for a period of time.  As I was installing updates after initial installation, the downloads often timed out.  This has continued when downloading other software or using web mail.  I tried to install the current driver from Edimax, but could not get it to fully install.  I then called Edimax and they said the usb network adapter should work fine without installing the driver. Any suggestions?  I am fairly new to networking and Ubuntu, so please keep that in mind with your responses.